# Does the Unique Product Property mean that there are only two elements in the set that can create any other in the set, given an operation?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, free-abelian-group, ordered-groups

I was under the impression that the way it's defined in the title was the correct way to interpret the UPP(as that was what I was searching for) from the definition here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235062/unique-product-groups-and-semigroups

but in my searching I found that diffuse groups are considered to have the UPP, and that any free abelian group is diffuse: https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-21/24.pdf

on the wiki for free abelian groups:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group#Examples_and_constructions
you can see that there's clearly more than one way to reach a given dot in the image on the right, and it says that "The integers, under the addition operation, form a free abelian group with the basis {1}", which seems to imply that it's some weird form of linear dependence, and therefore not the same as what I was looking for.

So is my understanding of the UPP correct, or am I barking up the wrong tree? Some of it is out of my depth, but only because I was looking to study more about a group,ring,etc. where all elements of a set can only be constructed by two other elements and the operator(perhaps making an exception for identity).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may have skipped over the quantifier $\exists$ at least  *one* element that can be uniquely written as a product etc. etc.

It didn't say *all* elements could only be written as products in one way.

So, $\Bbb Z$ would have the property, because given any two finite subsets, there's an element that can only be written as a product (in this case sum) in one way.

Let's play around with it for a moment.  Take $A=\{0,1,2\}$ and $B=\{0,1\}$.  Then $3$ can only be written as a product (sum) of elements of $A$ and $B$ in one way ($2+1=3$).

Comment: I had taken "for all nonempty finite subsets" meant that it would include all subsets with just one element, which would be to say all of them. What youre saying seems to coincide more with the free abelian group page though. I take it there's no formal definition for every element then.

Comment: I doubt it, @Jay.